# Does Chrome's Task Manager show memory leaks caused by Javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, memory-leaks, google-chrome-devtools, taskmanager

I have a web app which, against conventional wisdom, updates DOM opacity as the window is scrolled.  The performance is about what you'd expect, but the surprise comes from Chrome's Task Manager window (shortcut: `Shift + Esc`).  As I scroll the window, the Memory value rises indefinitely and never returns to its original level.  The Timeline and Profile panels in Chrome's Dev Tools don't reflect this memory growth.

I made [a small Fiddle to illustrate the problem](http://jsfiddle.net/Impirator/Mt89Q/5/).  Make sure you have the Task Manager open to watch the tab's Memory as you scroll the Results pane.

Is the Task Manager memory column affected by JavaScript memory leaks, or is this something beyond my control (apart from not doing the opacity-on-scroll effect)?

[image: Task Manager - Google Chrome]

Comment: Yes, the memory of a tab is affected by memory leaks, but you probably don’t have a memory leak. The browser draws new tiles each time you scroll, and it won’t get rid of them until it needs to. Have you done it until hundreds (thousands) of megabytes?

Comment: Also, I can’t reproduce this behaviour on Chromium 36.

Comment: You can check up the memory using Profile on Chrome dev tool. I've checked out the page you gave and there was no memory leak from the heap of tab.

Comment: Two things you should consider doing: first, the browser will fire a **lot** of "scroll" events. Your function probably only needs to respond every 30 milliseconds or so. Second, do your CSS updates in a `requestAnimationFrame()` callback. Those won't change memory consumption much but they'll be friendlier to the CPU.

Comment: [Here is a slightly modified fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/4Nkwe/2/)

Comment: @Pointy All fair points, and the real production code has a throttle in place so the CPU doesn't shoot itself.  A friendly note about the modified fiddle: if you hit the end of the scroll track not exactly on the 30ms tick, the last event to completely hide one triangle or the other will never fire, and thus leave it slightly visible.  Easily accounted for with boundary checking, just wanted to be thorough in case someone wants that code for something.

Comment: @minitech I got the production one to **500,000K** (!) by letting it go overnight.